# How do I know which version of WSE my project is using?

Tags: .net, asmx

I inherited an asmx web service. I am mostly familiar w/ WCF. How do I know which WSE version this older web service is using? 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0?

Comment: It may not be using WSE at all (if you're lucky). Look at the version of Microsoft.Web.Services you're using.

Comment: John, It references Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll. Thank You. Can you post this to an answer so you can get some points? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be using WSE at all (if you're lucky).

Look at the version of Microsoft.Web.Services you're using. If it's Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll, then you're using WSE 2.0 (even more obsolete than WSE 3.0).